# New to Elasticsearch - Installation of Ingest Attachment

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-mapping

I am new to the EKL tools and have installed Elasticsearch 2.2, but could not find ways to install the plugin ingest attachment processor as a substitute of mapper attachment.

Would anyone know any ways to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My take on this would be to follow below steps:**

1) Remove existing mapper plugin
 - sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin remove [pluginname]

2) Install ingest plugin
 - sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install [plugin_name]

Answer (score 0):

The [current Elasticsearch documentation (version 2.3)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/mapper-attachments.html) says the Mapper Attachments Plugin *will be deprecated* in Elasticsearch 5.0.0 which is currently in Alpha.  Mapper Attachments is not deprecated for the current release (v.2.3) or yours, and in fact the ingest-attachment plugin is not even available for 2.2 or 2.3.  So continue using mapper-attachment plugin for the time being.